# Symfony 2.8 Bind Dropdown using Propel

Tags: symfony, dropdown, propel, symfony-2.8

I have try to bind dropdown and add below code in my 
OrganizationBundle->Form->Tyep->OrganizationType.php file:

```
use Admin\SalesTeamBundle\Model\SalesTeam;
use Admin\SalesTeamBundle\Model\SalesTeamQuery;
use Admin\SalesTeamBundle\Form\Type\SalesTeamType;

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{ 
    $builder->add('salesTeamId', 'model' , array( 
        'class' => 'Admin\SalesTeamBundle\Model\SalesTeam',
        'required' => true,
        'multiple' => false,
        'expanded' => false,
        'label' => 'Sales Team',
        'query' => SalesTeamQuery::create()->orderByName(),
        'property' => 'name',
    ));
}
```

And I get this error:

> The type name specified for the service "propel.form.type.model" does not match the actual name. Expected "model", given "Propel\Bundle\PropelBundle\Form\Type\ModelType"

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `ModelType::class` instead of `model`

```
 $builder->add('salesTeamId', ModelType::class , array( 
       [...]
    ));
```